# winForms в monodevelop

Tags: c#, linux, winforms

Переношу проект с# c windows на linux.при попытке скомпилировать вылетает ошибка

> кажется, что windows management instrumentation отключена.необходимо для обнаружения использования ОЗУ и информации о видеоконтроллере
>   включите сервис windows management instrumentation

Как обойти это?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в Моно под линукс нет поддержки пространства имен Management

Comment: @Александр а нельзя заменить это?

Comment: не знаю. В Net Management берет инфу из WMI. А в линуксе нет такой службы по умолчанию. Так что не знаю, как ее заменить. Все-таки на линукс не все реализовано

Comment: В линукс нет WMI, но есть прямой доступ к таблице SMBIOS и псевдо-файлам типа /proc/.../stat, откуда можно выудить аналогичную информацию